# Ordernar uma LIST com base em outra LIST

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma classe que possui uma propriedade que é outra classe. Segue exemplo:

## Classe Menu

```
public class Menu implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private Integer orderVisibilidade;
    private GrupoMenu grupoMenu;
}
```

## Classe GrupoMenu

```
public class GrupoMenu  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private Integer ordemVisibilidade;
}
```

Bom, eu tenho um LIST de MENU `List<Menu> listMenu`.

Eu criei uma classe para ordenar pelo campo `ordemVisibilidade` da classe `GrupoMenu` e deu certo.

Como estou fazendo a chamada da ordenação:

```
OrdenaMenuPorGrupoMenu ordenaMenuGrupoMenu = new OrdenaMenuPorGrupoMenu();
Collections.sort(listMenu, ordenaMenuGrupoMenu);
```

## OrdenaMenuPorGrupoMenu

```
public class OrdenaMenuPorGrupoMenu implements Comparator<Menu> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Menu o1, Menu o2) {
        return o1.getGrupoMenu().getOrdemVisibilidade().compareTo(o2.getGrupoMenu().getOrdemVisibilidade());
    }

}
```

Porém, eu preciso ordenar também pelo campo `orderVisibilidade` da classe `Menu`, ou seja, eu preciso ordernar o grupo e depois para cada grupo ordernar os menus.

Se eu mandar ordenar pelo `GrupoMenu` e depois pelo `Menu`, ele reordena tudo apenas pelo `Menu`. Como faço essa comparação?

Comment: Tens de mostrar como estas a ordenar. Deve estar ai o problema.

Comment: `GrupoMenu` contem um ou vários `Menu`s?

Comment: Já que tá resolvido, uma dica, que ao meu ver é mais eficiente, seria implementar a interface `Comparable` na própria classe, com o próprio método na classe, sem utilizar classes extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal tentar isso?

```java
public class OrdenaMenuPorVisibilidade implements Comparator<Menu> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Menu o1, Menu o2) {
        int d = o1.getGrupoMenu().getOrdemVisibilidade().compareTo(o2.getGrupoMenu().getOrdemVisibilidade());
        if (d != 0) return d;
        return o1.getOrderVisibilidade().compareTo(o2.getOrderVisibilidade());
    }

}
```

Ele tenta comparar pela visibilidade do grupo. Se der empate (o que vai acontecer se os dois menus estiverem no mesmo grupo), então ele usa a visibilidade do menu para desempatar.

Comment: Deu certo a ordenação. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.